# How to unzip a zip file in Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: node.js, csv, parse-platform, download, unzip

I had a requirement in my Parse Cloud code - Express.js application to download a zip file from a website - [Link to NSE India stock download.](http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2015/MAY/cm13MAY2015bhav.csv.zip)

*Once the file is downloaded, I need to unzip it and read a CSV file inside it.*

This task seems to be impossible in Parse Cloud code as we could download only **JSON or url encoded data from website**.

I'm working on Parse, Express - Node.js application. I also tried including node modules to unzip the zip file but it seems to have a lot of dependency issues.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance,
Sudheesh C M